# Spring security 3.1.4 backdoor

Tags: spring, authentication

I have this problem:

in a java web-app (with spring and spring-security 3.1.4) there's a sso authentication; this means the user authenticates as soon as he log in on his pc.

The configuration is this:

```
<sec:http> 
    <sec:logout />
    <sec:form-login login-page="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/" /> 
    <sec:anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_GUEST" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="headersFilter" after="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="jaasFilter" after="SERVLET_API_SUPPORT_FILTER" />
</sec:http>
```

and this works (actually login.jsp doesn't exist because the user is already logged in as I said above).

Now the problem is that I want to have a "backdoor";this means there should be a login page for me and my team to test and mantain the app.

It should work like this:

-I call localhost/wepapp/myloginpage and I should see the myloginpage.jsp (this works now);

-I click on "login" button and I enter in the second " element" and if the login is ok then I should get redirected to "/" (this doesn't work and I'm simply redirected on "login");

-with the configuration below it seems that I can see "/" without authentication, too, if I call it (localhost/wepapp)

I tried this configuration but it doesn't work, I mean I can see "/" without authentication and I get redirected to login (I also tried other small variations but same result, more or less):

```
<sec:http pattern="/myloginpage">
    <sec:logout />
    <sec:form-login login-page="/myloginpage" default-target-url="/" />
</sec:http> 

<sec:http pattern="/login">
    <sec:logout />
    <sec:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/" />
    <sec:anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_GUEST" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="headersFilter" after="SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="jaasFilter" after="SERVLET_API_SUPPORT_FILTER" />
    </sec:http>
```

My myloginpage.jsp:

```
 <form action="login" method="POST">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </td>
    </tr>
  .........
  </form>
```

I also have the controller for myloginpage:

```
@Controller
public class Myloginpage {

publicMyloginpage() {

}

@RequestMapping("/myloginpage")
public String home() {
          return "myloginpage";
}
```

}

Thankx,
Adrian

Comment: *user authenticates as soon as he log in on his pc*. So basically there is no authentication?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the `<intercept-url>` tags to configure access to certain paths.

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

Comment: Thankx for the quick answer ! There is a SSO (single sign on) authentication...that means: when the user logs in on his pc, there is an application that gets his username and pass and creates a request header that is passed to the java web app; the request header is then passed by all filters so the user is autenticated without a login page. I should not/cannot use "intercept-url". There is no login page for the web app so the request-header comes from somewhere. My mission is to let's say "hack" this system so I have to prepapare the "myloginpage" above and send the my request

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the exact idea here. Do you mean to authenticate a visitor by a custom header?

Comment: yes...I need to create a page for me as developer. The customer will Always use the sso authentication system.